# Get number of items in cart of current anonymous user

Tags: users, commerce

I need to get the number of items in cart of current anonymous customer on the site. I am using Drupal 7 and Drupal Commerce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load the current anonymous user cart, you can use [`commerce_cart_order_load`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_order_load/7) something like this should suffice:

It gets the product count as separate line items and the product quantity including number of items per line item.

```
// Can leave blank or provide UID
$uid = 0; // anon
$product_count = 0;
$product_quantity_count = 0;

// Load cart order
if ($order = commerce_cart_order_load($uid)) {
  // Let's use the wrapper because it rocks
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

  // Loop over line items and increment product counter
  foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
    // If line item is a commerce product type
    if (in_array($line_item_wrapper->type->value(), commerce_product_line_item_types())) {
      // Increment counters
      // Individual product line item
      $product_count++;
      // Number of items of product line item (quantity)
      $product_quantity_count += $line_item_wrapper->quantity->value();    
    }
  }

  // Debug output
  drupal_set_message(t('User %uid has %count products in cart with a total of %quantity items', 
    array('%uid' => $uid, '%count' => $product_count, '%quantity' => $product_quantity_count)));
}
```

Comment: Oh... Sorry, but when I simply log in and just after that log off I have an error: "EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityDrupalWrapper->set() (line 736 of (...)\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc)." How can I fix it?

Comment: The above code doesn't use ->set() perhaps you have a misconfigured rule?

Comment: @ihateubercart I've also adjusted the code to ensure the order is returned prior to creating the wrapper, perhaps that will help.